# mysql query optimization given a sorting order and id being passed as parameter

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize this query:

```
SELECT ob.id, obs.relation
FROM object_relation obs , object_table ob
WHERE obs.parent_id = 'ID_being_passed_as_parameter'
AND ob.id = obs.child_id        
AND ob.deleted_object_flag=0    
AND ob.id_prefix in ('prefix_variAble_passed')
ORDER BY  (SELECT m.value FROM metadata_table 
m WHERE ob.version_id=m.version_id AND m.name='SORTING_CONDITION' )
```

Is is possible to optimize it?
Any suggestions would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

Your query sucks because it's executing the subquery in the `order by` for *every* row.

Most subqueries can be turned into joins. This is what you should do too, as well as use joins in your main query:

```
SELECT ob.id, obs.relation
FROM object_relation obs 
join object_table ob 
    on ob.id = obs.child_id 
    AND ob.deleted_object_flag=0 
    AND ob.id_prefix in ('prefix_variable_passed')
left join metadata_table m 
    on ob.version_id = m.version_id
    AND m.name = 'SORTING_CONDITION'
WHERE obs.parent_id = 'ID_being_passed_as_parameter'
ORDER BY m.value;
```

This use of `left join` allows for there to be no matching row in `metadata_table` but still appear in the results.

Note also moving the predicates into the `on` clause of the join where they can be applied *as the row is joined* rather than at the end, which is much more efficient as the temporary result set is as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you. That was of great help indeed. I appreciate the time you spent to help me out.